# Can I use the word 'scientist' instead of the word 'scholar'?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Can I use the word 'scientist' instead of the word 'scholar'? Is there an umbrella term, at least, if I'm not sure which one to use (I read dictionaries)? If not, how do I form an adjective from the latter? For example, 'a [scholarific?] paper'.

Comment: What exactly is the question? The word-request tag asks you to give a sentence in which you'd want to use the word—if you do that, we might be able to understand your question. The adjective form of "scholar" is "scholarly", but I don't think this answers your entire question, just part of it.

Comment: A scientist is one kind of scholar. You can refer to a physicist as a scientist, but not a historian. What kinds of scholars are you talking about?

Comment: In the (Indian) university environment, there is a difference.  A professor of science and/or technology who guides PhD students is a scientist; and the PhD students are called Research Scholars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use the word 'scientist' instead of the word 'scholar'?

No.  Not all scientists are scholars, and not all scholars are scientists.  Many scientists work in industry.

> Is there an umbrella term, at least, if I'm not sure which one to use (I read dictionaries)?

"Scholar" and "academic" are umbrella terms for those who either study or work at academic institutions or contribute to scholarly journals.  They won't cover those scientists who work in industry and have no connection to the universities.

Definitions from Lexico are:

- Academic (noun): A teacher or scholar in a university or other institute of higher education. ( https://www.lexico.com/definition/academic )
- Scholar (noun): A specialist in a particular branch of study, especially the humanities. ( https://www.lexico.com/definition/scholar)

> If not, how do I form an adjective from the latter? For example, 'a [scholarific?] paper'.

"Scholarly" or "academic".

Definitions from Lexico are:

- Academic (adj.): Relating to education and scholarship.
- Scholarly (adj.): Involving or relating to serious academic study. OR: Having or showing knowledge, learning, or devotion to academic pursuits.